# How can I tell if there is data between colons?

Tags: bash, wildcard

I have a script that checks if a string is valid like this:

```
if [[ $result != *:*:* ]]
```

This returns true for:

```
 X:X:X
 :X:
 :X:X
 X:X:
 X::X
 ::X
 X::
 ::
```

How can I make it fail for:

```
 X::X
 ::X
 X::
 ::
```

Comment: That looks like Bash, not Perl.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot My mistake. Yes. This is bash. Modified my question accordingly

Comment: Please do not put the language in the title (e.g. `Bash - How do I foo the bar?`). That's what tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
if [[ $result != *:?:* ]]
```